# Failed to upgrade ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 beacause package size mismatch

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade

I was upgrading my ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, using following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

everything is OK until I get following error message :

```
    Could not download the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have 
been kept. 

Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/account-plugins/account-plugin-facebook_0.10bzr13.03.26-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb 
Size mismatch 
Failed to fetch 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/friends/friends-facebook_0.1.3daily13.04.17.1~13.04-0ubuntu1_all.deb 
Size mismatch 



Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

what should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it via the GUI it may be easier?

Make sure you backup, it may cause you some frustration later on if not.

Start off with do-release-upgrade -c

if this fails You may need to install the update-manager-core package if your distro is no longer supported.